# asp.net mvc url routing: how to get particular link URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, url-routing

Given the following routing:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "RouteName", // Route name
                "ViewFoo/{FooId}",
                new { controller = "Foo", action = "View"}
            );
```

corresponding to the following action method:

```
public ActionResult View(string fooId = null)
{
  ...blah...
}
```

Precisely how would I call `Url.Action()` to get the string '/ViewFoo/4'? Or do I need to modify the routing somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Url.Action("View", "Foo", new { FooId = 4 })
```